# Div with position absolute is wider than its container

Tags: css, sass

In the following code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="cards-wrapper">
  <div class="cards_item">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card__header">
        <div class="=card__title">
          <div>title</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card__content">
        <p class="card__description">Some text</p>
        <p class="card__frequency">more text</p>
      </div>
      <div class="card__footer">
        <div class="card__tick"><input type="hidden" value="0"><label class="checkbox-container"><input type="checkbox" class="list-checkbox" value="false"><span class="checkmark"></span></label></div>
        <div class="card__see">Even more</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**SCSS**

```
  .cards-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    outline: 2px solid blue
  }

  .cards_item {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0.5rem;
  }

  .card {
    position: relative;
    flex: 0 1 100%;
    justify-self: stretch;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0.625rem;
    overflow: hidden;

    &__header {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
      align-items: center;
    }

    &__title {
      margin: 0;
    }

    &__frequency {
      margin-bottom: 80px;
    }

    &__footer {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0.8rem;
      display: inline-flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: space-between;
      width: 100%;
      outline: 2px solid red;
    }
  }
```

Why does **.card__footer** div with a width of 100% wider than its container?
It fits in the container if you change its width to 90%.
But something seems to be not right here.
Can someone help me please with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see that the container div has padding to it.

can you try this width value on your footer?

```
width: calc(100% - 1.25rem);
```

since you are using scss
`calc(100% - 2*0.625rem)`

Comment: 1.25rem is your padding value in container div * 2, (padding on right and left both)

Comment: It's working like a charm. I tried box-sizing: border-box; but it didn't work. Your solution works.